# Insert Date from java (eclipse) to Sql (workbench)

Tags: java, mysql

I entered the code and I wanted to send this data to the prepared table in Workbench (SQL). The system shows no connection. I work in an eclipse environment and I have problems to send data from jtable to Workbench

```
JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
    btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = null;

                conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tabela2?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","Jackpatu205");
                String insert = "insert into autohandel values (?, ? , ? , ?,?)";
                PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(insert);

                    ps.setString(1, "1");
                    ps.setString(2, "Citroen");
                    ps.setString(3, "2015");
                    ps.setString(4, "12500");
                    ps.setString(5,"France");
                    ps.executeUpdate();



                if (conn !=null) {
                    System.out.println("\nConnected Update");   

                    System.out.println(" --------------------------------------");      
                }
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("No Connection Update");
                }   
            //
        }
    });
```

Comment: `The system shows no connection.` - for more information about the problem print the actual exception message, not your own message.

Comment: I found an error.  I should write in this statement.

Comment: ps.setString(1, "1");

Comment: ps.setString(1, null);